# Unable to copy text from the terminal to external programs

Tags: vim, clipboard

**Aim: I want to copy my public ssh key generated on AWS Server to my github account.**

I have little experience with Ubuntu.
I use the ssh command from my laptop to connect to the AWS Server.
The operating system on both my laptop and AWS Server is Ubuntu trusty tar 14.04.

```
ssh -i /etc/ssh/aws_myhosts.pem ubuntu@XX.XX.253.101
```

This works.

I want to copy the contents of aws_myhosts.pem (my public ssh key) to my github account.

I can select the text using Vim (using pressing `v` first and keyboard arrows, no mouse is present), but can't copy and paste it to an external program (ie Github).

The problem occurs when I want to copy my public ssh key to Github.

I have installed `vim-gtk` as it has clipboard support. When I type

```
$ vim --version | grep clipboard  
+clipboard
+xterm_clipboard
```

I understand clipboard support is required.

It is said I should use `"+y` to copy text, but this has not worked.

What do I have to do to be able copy text from the terminal to external programs?

I've tried [Accessing the system clipboard using Vim](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/accessing-the-system-clipboard-from-vim/)

Comment: can you clarify, Ubuntu is the server you connect to? you connect from your laptop? What OS on the laptop and what program to connect to the server ? and then you want to copy text from where to where?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen <br/> 
I can to connect to the AWS Server (this uses Ubuntu, trusty 14.04),
from my laptop (this also uses Ubuntu, trusty 14.04).<br/> 
The command I use is <br/>
Thanks.
**`ssh -i /etc/ssh/aws_myhosts.pem ubuntu@XX.XX.253.101`**
<br/>
With this I'm now connected to the AWS Server.
<br/>  
***Aim: To copy text from the console on the AWS Server to Github (my public key address field).***
<br/>

Comment: Assuming you are running X on your laptop , select the text you want to copy with your mouse. Then go to your ssh terminal and hit the middle mouse button or push the wheel down. If you  have a two button mouse, configure the mouse so that if you hit both buttons at the same time it emulates a middle mouse click. see also http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Toggle_auto-indenting_for_code_paste

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, thanks but I don't have a mouse. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Muru, thanks for your answer, I'm working on it. This is all new to me, so I've not got it working yet.  I'll get back to you with feedback, thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

To use the clipboard that way, you must have X forwarding enabled `ssh -X` (or `ssh -Y`, depending on the settings).

See [How can I copy text to the system clipboard from Vim?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/96/205).

Answer (score 4):

Here is the answer I was looking for:

To connect type:

```
ssh -X -i /etc/ssh/aws_myhosts.pem ubuntu@XX.XX.XXX.XXX
```

Where

- `-X`  Enables X11 forwarding
- `-i`  Identity file
  The identity file selects a file from which the identity (private key) for RSA or DSA is read.
- `/etc/ssh/aws_myhosts.pem`  is the private key file (used by Amazon web services)
- `ubuntu@XX.XX.XXX.XXX` is the username at the remote host

When I typed the command above ie

```
ssh -X -i /etc/ssh/aws_myhosts.pem ubuntu@XX.XX.XXX.XXX
```

I received this message:

```
/usr/bin/xauth: file /home/ubuntu/.Xauthority does not exist
```

I used google to look up what this means from 
[Look under the post from hwttdz](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1863739)

ie How do you ceate a .Xauthority file for remote access

This says, you will get a

```
 /user/bin/xauth: file/home/username/.Xauthority does not exist
```

But the `.Xauthority` file is made for you on the spot. Knowing that, you can then open up a graphic application from the remote machine, like

```
gedit filename
```

Which worked for me. I typed

```
gedit ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

which allowed me to copy the text I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Rather a workaround, but you can just select the text and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to copy the selection to your clipboard

Answer (score 2):

As a work around, use `echo` or `cat` instead of vim to view the file. Highlight the data and use your middle button or `<ctrl-v>` or `<shift-insert>` to paste, whichever works best for you.